# Jira ServiceDesk Create-Request API - Add String[] to Custom Field (Java)

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

**Background:** Trying to set custom fields set in input to the Jira ServiceDesk Create-Request API call

**Success**: Tickets are being created. Single string value Custom-Fields are being set.

**Issue:** Having issues with Custom Fields with String[] values.

**My Code Snippet to set Custom Fields** :

```
    JSONObject args = new JSONObject();
    args.put("serviceDeskId", projectid);
    args.put("requestTypeId", issuetypeid);
    requestFieldValues.put("summary", summary);
    requestFieldValues.put("description", description);

    // Process Custom Fields
    if (customFields != null) {
      customFields().forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (value != null) {
          if (customFieldIdMap.get(key) != null) {
            try {
              if (isArray(value)) {
                List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String val : (String[]) value) {
                  listOfMaps.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                      put("value", val);
                    }
                  });
                }
                requestFieldValues.put(customFieldIdMap.get(key), listOfMaps);
                /*for (String val: (String[]) value) {
                  requestFieldValues.put(customFieldIdMap.get(key), new HashMap <String, String>() {{
                    put("value", val);
                  }});
                }*/
              } else {
                requestFieldValues.put(customFieldIdMap.get(key), new HashMap<String, String>() {
                  {
                    put("value", (String) value);
                  }
                });
              }
            } catch (JSONException exc) {
              customFieldErrors.append(exc.getMessage());
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
    args.put("requestFieldValues", requestFieldValues);
```

I have been going through multiple articles both here and from other sources, but none could resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both Jira's Text Field (multi-line) and Text Field (single line) store their value internally as a single String. The multi-line variant uses CR+LF(carriage return+line feed) to separate the strings being displayed.
So, sending a single string like `"a\r\nb"` should give you two lines with "a" and "b" respectively.

Note, I found a [KB article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-insert-a-new-line-when-using-lines-the-jira-core-rest-api-779160736.html) that only uses `\n` instead of `\r\n` so there might be differences between Jira versions.